# How to dynamically distribute a string of large content in two columns of a page in iTextpdf

Tags: java, itext

Hi I want to generate a Pdf that will contains two columns, and I have a single source(we can say single String object) of data. And I want this string data is fill in left column first then right column, after the page is complete create a new page and fill left column first and then right column and continue until the whole data is fill in all required pages.
For example: I have attached the images below
Please note that I have single source of data (String object).
[image]

Comment: For iText5, the movie column examples are a good resource: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-3.
For iText7, have a look at the ColumnRenderer example in the jumpstart tutorial: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers.

Comment: Thank you very much